# A \newcommand type option that runs all subarguments and saves static text

Tags: macros, sagetex

I am trying to write code that uses sage in it, and have a bit of a problem with randomizing stuff around the code. The sagetex part isn't too important (I don't think), what is important is that if I use a

```
\newcommand{\foo}{(SAGETEXHERE)}
```

then whenever I run the command `\foo` it reruns the sage text... which is a problem.

Here is an example of the current pseudo-code

```
\begin{sagesilent}
func1 = x - 3
func2 = x + 1
f = expand(func1*func2)
\end{sagesilent}

\newcommand{\foo}{\sage{f}}
```

Here, what would normally happen is sage silent runs sage, and creates the correct f = x^2 - 2x - 3. Then every time `\foo` is called, it reruns an instance of sage to go locate the definition of f in the sage file, and then sage will spit out the definition in text to `\foo` which then will display f.
This is taking a lot of compute time unnecessarily, and when things get randomized it all goes to hell.

Is there any way to force a command to take in the definition when it's defined, and then save that definition as straight up text so that I don't have to rerun sage to go find the definition of f every time I want to call `\foo`?

EDIT: I have come up with a non sage version that should be equivalent.

Using the lgc package, here's my MWE:

```
\usepackage[first=1]{lcg}
\newcommand{\Temp}{\genrand{A}{1}{10} \arabic{A}}
\begin{document}
\Temp
\Temp
\Temp
\end{document}
```

In this example the `\Temp` would give 3 different numbers, but what I am after is some way to build a second macro, maybe `\Temp2` so that it expands `\Temp` when `\Temp2` is defined, and then every time `\Temp2` runs it gives the same number. Notice this is by way of example, in this particular case I could save the first random number in a counter and then keep calling the counter, but that's not the point, I want to be able to do this at a macro definition level (so I can apply it to the sagetex context).

Any ideas?

Comment: can you make sage write something else eg `\def\foo{x^2 - 2x - 3}` rather than `x^2 - 2x - 3` ?

Comment: This would be ideal and it seems like something that should be possible, but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

Comment: hmm in that case I probably can't answer, I could make some guesses but it depends a bit on the timing of how sagetex hooks up the communication to sage.

Comment: After doing a whole lot more looking into this, I'm wondering if some trick using expansion would work? i.e. define the macro \foo and force it to expand the content (the \sage{f} part) at the definition stage, so that it expands and takes the input at that point instead of recalling \sage{f} each time? But I have no idea how to work with \expandafter \noexpand and all those commands too well...?

Comment: almost certainly `\sage` is not expandable.

Comment: I think there's a timing problem like @David Carlisle mentions. First run does .tex, second does sage, third does tex. Defining the command in the tex file means Sage hasn't run so you get a a tex error. I think the only way to get this approach to work is if the macro \foo and all uses of \foo are inserted as a string during the second pass. Those extra conditions probably make it too troublesome to implement.